# PowerBI report service - data flow questions

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

This is what I am trying to do: I have various SQL server databases with data. I created views in all of them. All views will need to be imported, and I specify their relationships. I want this to be refreshed nightly. I want to build various reports of the same data source.

1. Do I have to use a PowerBI desktop application to import data into PowerBI Report Service? [I have done this so far, but then can create new reports in the cloud on existing data. It would make sense to connect directly from PowerBI report service to my SQL servers.]
2. Once I uploaded data using a desktop application (as I have done so far), how can I view the data model in the report service once it is uploaded in the cloud?
3. In order to get routinely refreshed data I need to setup a gateway. Is the local PowerBI desktop application still involved in this process, or could I [in theory] delete the local desktop application that pushed the data in initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your questions:

1. You have two options, use PBI Desktop to connect to the data using import/direct query, then load it to the service. You can use dataflows to create an import based on your views, but you will then need to create reports from those. Using dataflows, you'll have to set up a refresh schedule, then for the dataset(s) built on top of those, you'll have to set another refresh schedule.
   You will be limited to the dataset sizes of 1GB for the workspace if importing data. You cannot use direct query on dataflows (unless you have enhanced compute with PBI premium). Once the dataset is loaded, you can then create new reports in the service or via desktop on top of that dataset. If possible it is recommended to use direct query.
2. To see the data model, you can use desktop to connect to PBI Service Dataset. This will connect in 'Live Connection' mode, and will be limited to that one dataset, you can't add others to it, Excel, CSV, SQL etc. You can also use Analyse in Excel, a plugin for Excel, that can connect to the data model. You can create new reports in the service for existing data models as well.
3. When creating the report in PBI Desktop it does not use the Gateway, you connect to your data sources as normal, then once you load the dataset to Power BI it will match the data sources in the file to the ones set up in the Gateway Admin settings. So you will still need PBI Desktop to create reports, but the gateway is there for the refreshing. The Desktop is not used in the process for refreshing. You could delete the workbook or application, but if you have to make changes, what will you refer to? (You could download a copy of the report from the service).+ It is easier to make changes in the desktop app, then the service, as there is a feature difference between dataset creation in the desktop vs service.